# Memory resident android Application

Tags: android

I'm writing an English to Persian dictionary for Android. It works fine as a standalone application, but I need it be resident in memory and  user be able to call ( run ) it on other applications.
For example, user is reading an English text from a web page and needs a word to be translated. He highlights the word, and dictionary application automatically shows the translation.

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have to update your application to get quires and return result.

Comment: Dear Arsalan . Actually I just want the dictionary be resident in memory and user be able to call ( run ) it on other applications.

Comment: You mean any application not just your application?

Comment: No. On you PC, have you used Babylon dictionary? Once you install it, you can right click on any word, anywhere, and see the translation. I want the same dictionary that can be called whenever user highlights a word, so he can see the translation. Please see the above image.

Comment: I think it can't be implemented in android, but i'm not sure. Unless android provide some high-light broadcast, so that you can register a global receiver.

Answer (score 2):

Currently it is not possible to add some action after selecting text.

But there is another approach, after user select some text, he can choose *share* button, and *share* it to your application. Your Android Manifest must contain something like this, to handle it:

```
                    <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
                            <data android:mimeType="image/*" ></data>
                    </intent-filter>
                    <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"></action>
                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
                            <data android:mimeType="image/*" ></data>
                    </intent-filter>
```